# Can you run a command to process an Azure SSAS Cube from Azure SQL in Elastic Jobs?

Tags: azure, powershell, elasticsearch, jobs, ssas-tabular

I have an Azure SQL database with some fact tables.  I have an SSAS Tabular Cube on an Azure Analysis Services database running on the same subscription.  The cube's source database is the Azure SQL database.

I have an elastic job which contains steps to calculate the fact tables in Azure SQL.  It does this daily.  I would like to have an additional step that would invoke the SSAS Tabular Cube to process with the latest information.

In an on-premise version - I could use SQL Agent to call a powershell script.  Azure SQL does not have an agent - only elastic jobs.  So it needs to be something that I can call using a T-SQL script.  i.e. the T-SQL could be a script that calls a powershell script but I'm not sure how that would work given that the script would need to be saved somewhere and there is nowhere to store scripts in Azure SQL.

Does anyone know if I can invoke the tabular cube processing command from Azure SQL using a T-SQL script?  Or if that isn't possible, would I be able to schedule the Azure SSAS Cube to process at a certain time every day?  Or is there some other Azure method I could use?

NOTE: Please do not suggest I switch to a virtual machine or managed instance - we need to use Azure SQL.  I am willing to use other Azure technology to achieve the same result but I can't change the source database from Azure SQL.

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Elastic Database Jobs just run TSQL.  Use [Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-refresh-azure-automation) instead.  You can schedule the Azure Automation job, and to coordinate the Elastic Database Job and the AAS processing you can [kick-off an Elastic Database Job by calling a stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-tsql-create-manage#begin-unplanned-execution-of-a-job).

Or manage the whole process in an [Azure Data Factory Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities).